# How to use Lombok with cucumber and guice

Tags: java-8, cucumber, lombok

This is the code. I am using cucumber and guice. I want to use Lombok. I am using java 8

```
@ScenarioScoped
public class VolumeCreateTestSteps {
private final VolumeSummaryPage volumeSummaryPage;
private final VolumeCreateTabs volumeCreateTabs;
private final VolumeCreatePropertyTab volumeCreatePropertyTab;

@Inject
public VolumeCreateTestSteps(VolumeSummaryPage volumeSummaryPage,
                             VolumeCreateTabs volumeCreateTabs,
                             VolumeCreatePropertyTab volumeCreatePropertyTab) {
    this.volumeSummaryPage = volumeSummaryPage;
    this.volumeCreateTabs = volumeCreateTabs;
    this.volumeCreatePropertyTab = volumeCreatePropertyTab;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No idea about cucumber, but Lombok+Guice work well together. The syntax is pretty hacky:

```
@ScenarioScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))
public class VolumeCreateTestSteps {
    private final VolumeSummaryPage volumeSummaryPage;
    private final VolumeCreateTabs volumeCreateTabs;
    private final VolumeCreatePropertyTab volumeCreatePropertyTab;
}
```

This funny `onConstructor=@__(@Inject)` using an undefined annotation names "two underscores" is a major hack, but it works for me since Java 5. Currently, I'm using Lombok 1.16.12 with Java 8. I guess, for Java 9, there's a problem, so the [newest Lombok version](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) uses a different hack:

```
onConstructor_=@Inject
```

Note the trailing underscore.